# System does not support specified encoding

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving an error: "System does not support specified encoding" when i run this procedure (I deleted my API key from the string as it is personal, if you want to test the string you can get an API key from developer.zoopla.com)

I am not sure why this happens. This code works just fine with another website.

```
Sub test()
Dim map As XMLMap
Set map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(2)
map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?minimum_beds=1&maximum_beds=1&area=Sands+End&api_key=xxxxxxx"
map.DataBinding.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to determine the type of encoding they use, or: Application.DefaultWebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingUTF8

Comment: i tried doing that, but I can't figure it out. In any case how would I solve the problem, if the file does not have the correct encoding? and what is correct encoding for Excel VBA?

Comment: Encoding is generated at the source. developer.zoople.com seem to be using [an encoding string of "ISO8859_1"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304625). From the VBA side you might need to match their encoding using the settings available for DefaultWebOptions

Comment: I tried Application.DefaultWebOptions.Encoding = msoEncodingISO88591Latin1 - still doesn't work. Perhaps this link will help? http://developer.zoopla.com/forum/read/102748

Comment: They are saying they use UTF-8 which still doesn't work for me when i change the settings.

Comment: The topic in that link is quite similar to your issue. It doesn't look like they are able to help with MSXML... the only other option is to "translate" the C++ call "IXMLDOMDocument::get_responseBody" to VBA and parse it cell by cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81045/discussion-between-paul-bica-and-joanna-mikalai).